# Android display Dimensions and Drawable size scaling

Tags: java, android, bitmap, screen, scale

It is the next stage of: 
[Scale and align in custom android AnalogClock hands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25296081/scale-and-align-in-custom-android-analogclock-hands)
...this one.

Soon I realized that a Drawable can not be scaled, if it fits the size box, then it will be displayed. Otherwise not. So now I need a Bitmap to scale it and then convert back to Drawable and draw it. It doesn't seem elegant, but according to what I found, I don't see any other way.

(Idea is to create own alarm app with some special tricks. Firstly, I need clock hands. For creating custom clock, I used own class, which extends View. Hour and minute hands are PNG images. They should be located in the center of the screen, but they are not even visible. **Emulator do not display the clock at all, and is not throwing any ecxeptions (basic layer is displayed)**)

Again I need screen dimensions to set up size of Hour and Minute hands. The code now looks as:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageView;



@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class Clock extends ImageView {

private Drawable mHourHand;
private Drawable mMinuteHand;

private int sizeXHour;
private int sizeXMinute;
private int sizeYHour;
private int sizeYMinute;
private int xHour;
private int xMinute;
private int yHour;
private int yMinute;
private int w;
private int h;

private Drawable Hh;
private Bitmap HourHnd;
private Drawable Mh;
private Bitmap MinuteHnd;

private boolean mAttached;

static private float mMinutes;
static private float mHour;
private boolean mChanged;

Context mContext;

// Getters&setters

protected float getmMinutes() {
return mMinutes;
}

protected static void setmMinutes(float mMinutes) {
Clock.mMinutes = mMinutes;
}

protected float getmHour() {
return mHour;
}

protected static void setmHour(float mHour) {
Clock.mHour = mHour;
}


//Ctors

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public Clock(Context context) {
super(context);
Resources r = context.getResources();
mContext=context;

Hh = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.hours);
HourHnd = ((BitmapDrawable)Hh).getBitmap();

Mh = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.minuts);
MinuteHnd = ((BitmapDrawable)Mh).getBitmap();   

// Here I try to take screen dimensions    

WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
{

    DisplayMetrics metrics = mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

    h = metrics.heightPixels;
    w = metrics.widthPixels;

}
else
{
    Display d = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    h = d.getWidth();
    w = d.getHeight();
}


    sizeXHour = w/3;
    sizeYHour = Hh.getIntrinsicHeight()*sizeXHour/Hh.getIntrinsicWidth();

    xHour = sizeXHour/2;
    yHour = sizeYHour/2;

    mHourHand = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(HourHnd, sizeXHour, sizeYHour, true));   // Here it says that sizeXHour etc. is 0;

    sizeYMinute = h/4;
sizeXMinute = Mh.getIntrinsicWidth()*sizeYMinute/Mh.getIntrinsicHeight();

xMinute = sizeXMinute/2;
yMinute = sizeYMinute/2;

mMinuteHand = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(MinuteHnd, sizeXMinute, sizeYMinute, true));


setWillNotDraw(false);
}



@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public Clock(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
    //setWillNotDraw(false);
    Resources r = context.getResources();
     mContext=context;


     Hh = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.hours);
     HourHnd = ((BitmapDrawable)Hh).getBitmap();

     Mh = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.minuts);
     MinuteHnd = ((BitmapDrawable)Mh).getBitmap();   


     WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

     //if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
     //{

        //DisplayMetrics metrics = mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

        //h = metrics.heightPixels;
        //w = metrics.widthPixels;

     //}
     //else
     //{
         Display d = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
         h = d.getWidth();
         w = d.getHeight();
     //}


        sizeXHour = w/3;
        sizeYHour = Hh.getIntrinsicHeight()*sizeXHour/Hh.getIntrinsicWidth();

        xHour = sizeXHour/2;
        yHour = sizeYHour/2;

        mHourHand = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(HourHnd, sizeXHour, sizeYHour, true));

        sizeYMinute = h/4;
        sizeXMinute = Mh.getIntrinsicWidth()*sizeYMinute/Mh.getIntrinsicHeight();

        xMinute = sizeXMinute/2;
        yMinute = sizeYMinute/2;

        mMinuteHand = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(MinuteHnd, sizeXMinute, sizeYMinute, true));


     setWillNotDraw(false);

}


@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public Clock(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
        int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        Resources r = context.getResources();
        //TypedArray a =
        //context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.AnalogClock, defStyle, 0);
         mContext=context;


         //mHourHand = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.hours);
         Hh = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.hours);
         HourHnd = ((BitmapDrawable)Hh).getBitmap();


         //mMinuteHand = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.minuts);
         Mh = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.minuts);
         MinuteHnd = ((BitmapDrawable)Mh).getBitmap();   



         WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
         //if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
         //{

         // DisplayMetrics metrics = mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

            //h = metrics.heightPixels;
         // w = metrics.widthPixels;
             //h = size.x;
             //w = size.y;
         //}
         //else
        // {
             Display d = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
             h = d.getWidth();
             w = d.getHeight();
         //}


            sizeXHour = w/3;
            sizeYHour = Hh.getIntrinsicHeight()*sizeXHour/Hh.getIntrinsicWidth();

            xHour = sizeXHour/2;
            yHour = sizeYHour/2;

            mHourHand = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(HourHnd, sizeXHour, sizeYHour, true));

            sizeYMinute = h/4;
            sizeXMinute = Mh.getIntrinsicWidth()*sizeYMinute/Mh.getIntrinsicHeight();

            xMinute = sizeXMinute/2;
            yMinute = sizeYMinute/2;

            mMinuteHand = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(MinuteHnd, sizeXMinute, sizeYMinute, true));


         setWillNotDraw(false);
}



@Override
protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();

    if (!mAttached) {
        mAttached = true;
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();

        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED);

    }

}



@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {


    //int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
    int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    //int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
    int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

    int width = widthSize; 
    int height = heightSize;


    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);


}


@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    mChanged = true;
    this.invalidate();
}




@SuppressWarnings({ "deprecation" })
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    boolean changed = mChanged;
    if (changed) {
        mChanged = false;
    }


        canvas.rotate(mHour / 12.0f * 360.0f, xHour, yHour);
        if (changed) {
        mHourHand.setBounds((w / 2) - xHour, (h / 2) - yHour, sizeXHour, sizeYHour);
                }
        mHourHand.draw(canvas);
        //canvas.restore();
        canvas.save();



        canvas.rotate(mMinutes / 60.0f * 360.0f, xMinute, yMinute);

        if (changed) {
        mMinuteHand.setBounds((w / 2 - xMinute), (h / 2 - yMinute), sizeXMinute, sizeYMinute);
        /
        }
        mMinuteHand.draw(canvas);
        //canvas.restore();
        canvas.save();


}
        }
```

Sorry for that large code again. Now the graphic layout manager in Eclipse states this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:808)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:787)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:719)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:595)
at ee.st.running.dreamyclock.Clock.<init>(Clock.java:268)
at ee.st.running.dreamyclock.Clock.<init>(Clock.java:161)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(    at       sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.instantiateClass(ProjectCallback.java:438)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.loadView(ProjectCallback.java:190)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:207)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:132)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:802)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:778)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:500)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:381)
```

In result, sizeXHour etc is 0; I am not sure that clock hands will be drawn at all, but I need to acquire screen dimensions nevertheless. Are there any possible ideas?

P.S. Exception is firstly here:
                    mHourHand = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(HourHnd, sizeXHour, sizeYHour, true));

Comment: Please, could you indicate in the code where the exception is happening ? I mean, where i line 268 of Clock ?

Comment: Sure. It is here: "              mHourHand = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(HourHnd, sizeXHour, sizeYHour, true)); " (and I think in sace of mMinuteHand will be just the same)

Comment: It looks like to me that either, because of successive integral divisions you obtain width or height that are zero (which seems unlikely to me), or that your drawables don't have an intrinsic width or height and so the values returned by their functions is zero.

Comment: But how is the second possible: both .PNG pictures are large...

Comment: Yes seems unlikely to me too. Why don't you set a breakpoint and see the content of the variable ? Or at least do some log of the values from which size and height are derived to see where the error comes from ?

Comment: Just one other guess : is this error happening during test, or inside visual editor in eclipse or android studio ?

Comment: HourHands original size is 16x200 px and MinuteHand 11x300 px on my PC. Well, not so big. When running on emulator, LogCat gives only Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE...:16384  - and there are no more errors

Comment: This is because of visual editor. See `View.isInEditMode()`

Comment: This error now happens in Eclipse visual editor. As an emulator I use Genymotion Samsung Galaxy S4 (It should work there) and it just do not display the Clock (displays the layer etc)

Comment: But there's no exception thrown in the emulator right ?

Comment: Yes, emulator throws no exceptions now. And just not displays clock at all

Comment: Not displaying is another error. Can you either edit your question or post a new one ?

Comment: Sure. Now I specified it. Hopefully, it will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this exception appears because eclipse cannot fully resolve some attributes such as styles, etc ... It is explained in the visual editor when the error occurs. Some workaround is to use `View.isInEditMode()`.

As for getting the size of the screen, the code you use (with `Display`) is correct and should work. If the clock doesn't appear, this means something else is wrong, not measurements.

I consider measuring the size of the screen a bad idea in general, because you make the assumption that your view matches the whole screen. But nothing prevents your view to be placed inside some other container and therefore have a real size that's smaller.

I suggest then, that you use the bounds of your view using `View.getWith()` and `View.getHeight()`.
Note : since a view is measured after its construction, using these methods in the constructors returns 0. You have to wait until the view has been laid out to retrieve its dimension : use for this `View.getViewTreeObserver().setOnGlobalLayoutListener`.

---

Also :

- After your view is laid out, `onDraw` will automatically be called, so there's no need to call `invalidate` at the end of `onMeasure`.
- The boolean changed has no effect (it seems). If the idea was to use it to only allow drawing the clock if size changed, it is a bad idea : this will result in your view being 'erased' when it is invalidated until its bounds change.

---

Here is how i made it work :

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class Clock extends View {

    private Drawable mHourHand;
    private Drawable mMinuteHand;

    private Drawable Hh;
    private Drawable Mh;

    private boolean mAttached;

    static private float mMinutes = 43;
    static private float mHour = 5;

    Context mContext;

    // Getters&setters

    protected float getmMinutes() {
        return mMinutes;
    }

    protected static void setmMinutes(float mMinutes) {
        Clock.mMinutes = mMinutes;
    }

    protected float getmHour() {
        return mHour;
    }

    protected static void setmHour(float mHour) {
        Clock.mHour = mHour;
    }

    // Ctors

    {
        initView();
    }

    public Clock(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public Clock(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public Clock(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    private void initView() {
        Resources r = getContext().getResources();
        mContext            = getContext();
        Hh                  = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.hours);
        Mh                  = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.minuts);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();

        if (!mAttached) {
            mAttached = true;
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();

            filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK);
            filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED);
            filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED);

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        int w               = r - l;
        int h               = b - t;

        mHourHand           = Hh;
        mMinuteHand         = Mh;

        // They will always be drawn centered inside the view
        mHourHand.setBounds(
                (w - mHourHand.getIntrinsicWidth()) / 2,
                (h - mHourHand.getIntrinsicHeight()) / 2,
                (w + mHourHand.getIntrinsicWidth()) / 2,
                (h + mHourHand.getIntrinsicHeight()) / 2
        );
        mMinuteHand.setBounds(
                (w - mMinuteHand.getIntrinsicWidth()) / 2,
                (h - mMinuteHand.getIntrinsicHeight()) / 2,
                (w + mMinuteHand.getIntrinsicWidth()) / 2,
                (h + mMinuteHand.getIntrinsicHeight()) / 2
        );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        // Rotate the center of the view (here the canvas is clipped and translated so that its clipped bounds are these of this view).
        canvas.save();
        canvas.rotate(mHour * 360/12, getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2);
        mHourHand.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();

        canvas.save();
        canvas.rotate(mMinutes * 360/12, getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2);
        mMinuteHand.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }
}
```

Then, here's a test, running inside an `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2` :

```
public void test() throws InterruptedException {
    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.clock_layout);
        }
    });
    Thread.sleep(3000);
}
```

And the layout file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="ee.st.running.dreamyclock.MainActivity"
    android:background ="@drawable/clockk" >
    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <!-- A modified layout params to match_parent, wrap_content results in the view having size (0,0) -->
    <com.example.clock.Clock
         android:id="@+id/clock"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_alignTop="@+id/view1"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I didn't understood all your scaling code, so i just got rid of it, and made as simple as possible, you can then work from this and add some resizing code if needed.

Comment: Thank you for answering. About the screen: yes, I knew it. Screen dimensions were taken for testing the app - will the clock be showed or not. View dimensions sounds as a good idea.

Am I correctly understood, that 
if(!isInEditMode()) - I should put in onDraw method, not in constructors?

Comment: Maybe the best is in `View.onSizeChanged()` or ` View.onLayout` : you calculate only when size changes and layout your clock drawables, and not every time the clock has to be drawn

Comment: You mean to put !isInEditMode there (Clock: onSizeChanged which is overrided)? I see some logic, yes. I'll test it right away

Comment: I put it in onSizeChanged, then in onDraw, but again it didn't. Maybe it is just always in edit mode?

Comment: Send me the view and the resources that are needed to make it run, i'll give it a try tomorrow

Comment: Thank you! Can you give your mail where to send, or attach them somewhere here?

Comment: I wouldn't wish to post it here. Can you send me some zip using dropbox, or whatever file sharing you want then post the link for the download ?

Comment: Thank you! It finally works. Now I am trying the resizing part. I made a resize method which returns BitmapDrawable which is resized using parameters View.getWidth/Height as you adviced, or alternatively I tried to use w and h from onLayout method (calling for example mHourHand = resize(Mh, sizeXHour, sizeYHour) + call if (!isInEditMode). It do not display arrows again. I think all troubles with visibility was because of resizing. Basicly I need a hour hand width always = 1/3 of layer (depending on display) width and minute hand always = 1/4 of layer height, so they could look similar anywhere

Comment: Yes, i had the same problem that disappeared magically when i got rid of the `ScaleDrawable` i had put around the hands

Comment: But I did not use ScaleDrawable, just BitmapDrawable instead. I tried ScaleDrawable also, and it didnt work